# Dynamically update a php array with a function

Tags: php, arrays

I have multiple sitemaps and I would like to merge them all, but before merging them, I need to append a unique variable to all values in all arrays.

```
// The global variable
define("BASE_URL", "http://domain.com");
$sitemap_full = [ "home" => BASE_URL ];

// One of the arrays
$sitemap_example = [
  "foo" => "/bar",
  "gnu" => "/lar"
];
```

Since I have multiple of those arrays, I wanted to create a function that will append the link.

```
function pushToSitemap($initial_sitemap, $sitemap) {
    foreach ($initial_sitemap as $title => $url) {
      return $sitemap[$title] = BASE_URL . $url;
    }
}
```

And in action in will be:

```
pushToSitemap($sitemap_example, $sitemap_full);
```

But this just doesn't work because if I `print_r($sitemap_full);` it will display `Array( "home", "http://domain.com" );`.

What really annoys me is that if in the function I echo them, they will be echoed.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

It should display

```
Array(
  "home" => "http://domain.com"m
  "foo" => "http://domain.com/bar",
  "gnu" => "http://domain.com/lar
);
```

Comment: you're returning inside the very first iteration of `foreach` in your `pushToSitemap()` function, so it never continues iterating; only return after the `foreach` loop terminates

Comment: That ^^^^ and then maybe you should show us what you want the array to look like after you have fiddled with it, as its not exactly obvious to me

Comment: `var_dump(array_merge($sitemap_full, array_map(function($value) {return BASE_URL . $value; }, $sitemap_example)));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems lie inside your `foreach` function:

```
function pushToSitemap($initial_sitemap, $sitemap) {
    foreach ($initial_sitemap as $title => $url) {
      return $sitemap[$title] = BASE_URL . $url;
    }
}
```

You are **returning** just a single item, what's more, the formatting is off.

Instead,

```
function pushToSitemap($initial_sitemap, $sitemap) {
    foreach ($initial_sitemap as $title => $url) {
      $sitemap[$title] = BASE_URL . $url;
    }
    return $sitemap;
}

$sitemap_full = pushToSitemap($sitemap_example, $sitemap_full);
```

Comment: I guess he doesn't even want to return anything and just do the action so the Sitemaps are "refreshed".

Comment: @DawidZbiński - how do you figure?

Comment: Ok, my bad. Now I realized that he wants to merge them.

Comment: @dcdeiv you have to reset the `$sitemap_full` variable to the contents of the function: `$sitemap_full = pushToSitemap($sitemap_example, $sitemap_full);`